# Strip out "-" from variable

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a variable which has this structure:

```
$catname = 'this-is-my-category';
```

How can I strip the "-" and get:

```
$catname = 'this is my category';
```

Comment: that would be just an replace in the string... `$catname = str_replace('-', ' ', $catname);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function like this:

```
$catname = str_replace('-', ' ', $catname);
```

This would replace every occurence of `-` with  in your string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$catname = str_replace('-', ' ', $catname);
```

Answer (score 1):

For character-wise replacing the ideal function is [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$catname = strtr($catname, "-", " ");
```

This makes less effort if you later decide to replace e.g. underscores too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$catname = str_replace("-", " ", $catname);
```